# How to create a crawl for whatsapp with puppeteer?

Tags: puppeteer

I try create a crawl for whatsapp with puppeteer in  headless mode but whatsapp only support Chrome. (Chrome not work in headless mode)

[image]

Comment: So... what code are you using? Any error messages in the console logs? Any exceptions / timeouts? You need to supply more information than "it doesn't work in headless mode".

Answer (score 1):

Set your user agent to report it is chrome.

`await page.setUserAgent('5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36');
await page.goto('https://www.watsUpUrl.ok');`